# Segmentation Fault in the implementation of a sorting function

Tags: c++, sorting, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am trying to implement a sorting algorithm based on psuedocode provided for my programming class and me and my partner have been consistently getting (core dumped) errors, usually Segmentation Fault specifically. I understand that usually means the program is trying to access memory it is not allowed to, but I'm unsure how to fix the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void FlipFlopSort(int *Array, int begin, int end){
    int length = (end-begin);
    float midh = 2*(float)length/3;
    midh = ceil(midh);
    float midl = (float)length/3;
    midl = ceil(midl);
    //cout << "size of sorted area = " << length << endl;
    if(length<=2){
        //cout << "Length = 2" << endl;
        if(Array[begin] > Array[begin+1]){
            swap(Array[begin], Array[begin+1]);
        }
    }else{
        //cout << "Recursion Begin 1" << endl;
        FlipFlopSort(Array, begin, midh);
        //cout << "Recursion End" << endl;
        FlipFlopSort(Array, midl, end);
        //cout << "Recursion Begin 2" << endl;
        FlipFlopSort(Array, begin, midh);
    }
}

int main(){
    // Declare Variables and Read Inputs
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int Array[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> Array[i];
    }

    FlipFlopSort(Array, 0, n);


    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
         if(i != (n-1)){
             cout << Array[i] << " ";
         }else{
             cout << Array[i] << endl;
         }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Time to fire up a debugger and debug your code. It's the best way to see what's going on. Also `Array[n]` is not valid in C++, even if some compiler extension support it. Use `std::vector` which is the correct container.

Comment: Are you by any chance using code:blocks and there is no decent debugging info?

Comment: I just tried to debug my program and I got a new message but one I don't particularly understand: it stated that there is a Segmentation fault 0x0000555555554d35 in std::ceil. And then continued on to say I couldn't access memory at /usr/include/c++/7/cmath:166

Comment: This is where you look down the stack to find *where* in your code things went wrong.

Comment: There should be a way in your debugger to walk up the callstack to your code. When you get to you code it should show you what line of your program was running when the crash occurred. In Visual Studio there is a `Stack Frame` combo box on the debugging toolbar and a call stack window / view. Both of these allow you to walk up / switch the callstack.

Comment: I honestly don't know as much about debugging as I should, my profs have never made it a point to teach for some reason so I am trying to learn as I go. I am using g++ to compile and while trying to find the error what I think I've found is that at some point in my FlipFlopSort function end = 0, and begin = -1 which causes it to attempt to access negative indexes I believe, but I am unable to find out how and when this is occuring

Comment: One thing that stands out is that if `length` is 0 or 1, you still `swap` elements. That can't be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with:

```cpp
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int Array[n];
```

1. Why is n a signed type? arrays sizes can't be declared as signed types.
2. C++ strictly forbids declaring variable sized array on the stack (i.e. the way you did). It is also a deprecated feature of C. You should write instead:

```cpp
    int* Array = new int[n];
```

One of the reasons you might be getting a segmentation fault is because of the following line:

```cpp
    if (length <= 2) {
        //cout << "Length = 2" << endl;
        if (Array[begin] > Array[begin + 1]) {
            swap(Array[begin], Array[begin + 1]);
        }
    }
```

1. If length is less-than or equal to 2, does it mean it has at least 2 elements? It might have 0 or 1. You should add a check in the beginning of your function:

```cpp
void FlipFlopSort(int *Array, int begin, int end){
    int length = (end-begin);
    if (length <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Another reason, is because you compute the middle **sizes** and not indices, meaning, you don't add begin to them.

consider: begin=100, end=103. -> length = 3, midl = 1 and midh = 2. Makes sense? no! These are not valid indices in this context. You should have written

```cpp
midh += begin;
midl += begin;
```

after their computation.

Last thing, you should avoid using floating points (unless you REALLY need to) so I would write:

```cpp
    const int midl = begin + length / 3;
    const int midh = begin + 2 * midl;
```

It is not equivalent to what you wrote, but it still works, while your's is risky (ceiling values is fishy beacause you might find yourself over the end of the array).

```cpp
void FlipFlopSort(int* Array, int begin, int end) {
    const int length = end - begin;
    if (length <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    const int midh = begin + 2 * length / 3;
    const int midl = begin + length / 3;

    //cout << "size of sorted area = " << length << endl;
    if (length <= 2) {
        //cout << "Length = 2" << endl;
        if (Array[begin] > Array[begin + 1]) {
            swap(Array[begin], Array[begin + 1]);
        }
    }
    else {
        FlipFlopSort(Array, begin, midh);
        FlipFlopSort(Array, midl, end);
        FlipFlopSort(Array, begin, midh);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not check correctness of the algorithm itself

Comment: I can't begin to thank you enough, I've been working on this for days and have been unable to find out the solution, turns out that not realizing I need to add the begin was a HUGE issue. Again, thank you very much for your help! So far every test I've made works, and once I test all the cases, even if there is failures it should be easier to fix from here

Comment: @Michael The `ceil` operations are necessary for the algorithm to work. It can be done using plain integers too though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just found this issue when testing larger number sets, if I don't use ceil the algorithm fails, if I use ceil there is a Segmentation Fault. I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that `length` is at least 2 when you `swap`, or else you'll be swapping numbers out of bounds. Your `midl` and `midh` values are currently wrong. They are relative to `begin`, so you need to add `begin` to them. You could however add `midl` to the `Array` itself and skip the `begin` parameter in your function to simplify the interface.

I'd also replace the floating point `std::ceil` operations with an integer version.

```
// A function to do integer division and return the ceil value
size_t DivCeil(size_t dividend, size_t divisor) {
    return 1U + ((dividend - 1U) / divisor);
}

void FlipFlopSort(int* Array, size_t length) {
    if(length > 2) {
        // calculate midl & midh
        size_t midl = DivCeil(length, 3U);
        size_t midh = DivCeil(2U * length, 3U);

        FlipFlopSort(Array, midh);
        // add midl to Array and sub midl from length
        FlipFlopSort(Array + midl, length - midl);
        FlipFlopSort(Array, midh);
    } else if(length == 2) {
        if(Array[1] < Array[0]) {
            // swap the values
            std::swap(Array[0], Array[1]);
        }
    } // else length < 2 ... don't do anything
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    size_t n;
    if(std::cin >> n) { // check that the user entered a number
        // don't use VLA:s, use a std::vector instead
        std::vector<int> Array(n);

        for(size_t i = 0; i < Array.size(); ++i) {
            std::cin >> Array[i];
        }

        FlipFlopSort(Array.data(), Array.size());

        for(int value : Array) {
            std::cout << value << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

If you want your sorting algorithm to be made more generic and usable with the standard containers, you could replace the input parameters with iterators.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::iter_swap
#include <iterator>  // std::distance, std::next

// A function to do integer division and return the ceil value
template<typename T>
T DivCeil(T dividend, T divisor) {
    return 1 + ((dividend - 1) / divisor);
}

template<typename It>
void FlipFlopSort(It begin, It end) {
    auto length = std::distance(begin, end);     // iterator version of "length = end-begin"
    static constexpr decltype(length) two = 2;   // constant of the same type as length
    static constexpr decltype(length) three = 3; // -"-

    if(length > two) {
        // calculate midl & midh iterators
        auto midl = std::next(begin, DivCeil(length, three));
        auto midh = std::next(begin, DivCeil(two * length, three));

        FlipFlopSort(begin, midh);
        FlipFlopSort(midl, end);
        FlipFlopSort(begin, midh);
    } else if(length == two) {
        if(*std::next(begin) < *begin) {
            // swap the values pointed at by the iterators
            std::iter_swap(begin, std::next(begin));
        }
    } // else length == 1 or 0 ... don't do anything
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    size_t n;
    if(std::cin >> n) {
        std::vector<int> Array(n);

        for(size_t i = 0; i < Array.size(); ++i) {
            std::cin >> Array[i];
        }

        FlipFlopSort(std::begin(Array), std::end(Array));

        for(int value : Array) {
            std::cout << value << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```